# set icon and title in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml

i want to set icon and title in fragment  but only able to display title not icon.

Here is my code that i have done.

```
    package com.amira.amira.amira.Board.Clothes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.amira.amira.amira.ChatCalendarProfile.Calendar.CalendarFragment;
import com.amira.amira.amira.ChatCalendarProfile.Profile.ProfileFragment;
import com.amira.amira.amira.R;


public class BoardClothesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    Drawable myDrawable;
    String title;
    Context mContext;
    public BoardClothesAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context mContext) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position ) {
            case 0:
            return new HeadFragment();
            case 1:
            return new DressFragment();
            case 2:
            return new JeansFragment();
            case 3:
            return new ShirtFragment();
            case 4:
            return new BalletFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = null;
        ImageSpan span;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                myDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.head);
                title = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.title_head);
                sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   " + title);

                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                return sb;

            case 1:
                myDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dress);
                title = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.title_dress);
                sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   " + title);
                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                return sb;

            case 2:
                myDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.shirt);
                title = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.title_shirt);
                sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   " + title);
                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                return sb;

            case 3:
                myDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.leg);
                title = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.title_jeans);
                sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   " + title);
                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                return sb;

            case 4:
                myDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ballet);
                title = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.title_ballet);
                sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   " + title);
                myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                return sb;
        }
        return sb;
    }
}
```

and there is the activity

```
    package com.amira.amira.amira.Board.Clothes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.amira.amira.amira.Board.Accessories.BoardAccessoriesActivity;
import com.amira.amira.amira.ChatCalendarProfile.CategoryAdapter;
import com.amira.amira.amira.R;

public class BoardClothesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewClothes;
    private TextView textViewAccessories;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_board_clothes);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        textViewClothes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_clothes);
        textViewAccessories = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_accessories);
        BoardClothesAdapter adapter = new BoardClothesAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        textViewAccessories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                startActivity( new Intent(BoardClothesActivity.this, BoardAccessoriesActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

In this pic,  only display in my application title without icon.Could you please any idea how to display section page adapter with icon and title.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Drawable myDrawable;
@Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            SpannableStringBuilder sb = null;
            ImageSpan span;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image1);
                    sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("  Page1"); // space added before text for convenience

                    myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                    sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    return sb;
                case 1:
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image2);
                    sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("  Page2"); // space added before text for convenience

                    myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                    sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    return sb;
                case 2:
                    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image3);
                    sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("  Page3"); // space added before text for convenience

                    myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                    sb.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    return sb;
            }
            return  sb;
        }
```

To display only title use the below code

```
private String[] title = {
        "shirt",
        "pant",
        "jeans",
    }

     @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

                return title [position % title .length];
    }
```

Comment: myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image1);                   
myDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dress);
the method getRecources() with out mContext not work

Answer (score 0):

First, retrieve the action bar, then you can modify title and icon :

```
    ActionBar bar = ((AppCompatActivity) getSupportActionBar();

    if (bar == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Change title
    bar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.my_title));

    // Change icon
    bar.setIcon(myIcon);
```

Answer (score -1):

Find solve here

Create icon array like this:

```
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts};`
```

And `setIcon` to `tabLayout`:

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
```

References:

- https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/
- http://www.androiddeft.com/tablayout-viewpager-android/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Only one note: if you have copy-pasted some content from the site, put `>` (blockquotes), so you can avoid further issues.